# Borders of my table are not completely showing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a form in a structure of a table. However, it seems that once I placed my boxes text to the label, the outside border loses its structure and part of the border disappears. I am not sure what is causing.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test model</title>
<style>
    div.box{height:.14in; width:.14in; border: 1px solid black}
    td.box{padding:0;}
    body{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:10pt;background-color:#FFFFCC;margin-top:2px;margin-left:3px}
    .highlight{background-color:#D8DCE7}
    .p12px{padding-left:12px;vertical-align:top;}
    table.q{width:660px;border:1px solid black;border-top-width:0;padding-left:2px;}
    table.qFirst{width:660px;border:1px solid black;}
    table{border-collapse:collapse}
    table td{padding:1px}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class='qFirst'>
    <tr class='highlight'><td class='p12px'><b>Title of Table</b></td></tr>
    </table>
<table class='q'>
    <tr><td>Label 0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Label 1</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>Yes</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>No</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Label 2</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>Yes</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>No</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Label 3</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>Yes</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>No</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Label 4</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>Yes</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>No</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Label 5</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>Yes</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>No</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Label 6</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>Yes</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>No</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Label 7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Label 8</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I can use Javascript if that will help, but I can't use JQuery.

Comment: [I don't understand the problem - the table looks like it has borders to me.](http://jsfiddle.net/aok7wck0/)

Comment: @Pointy try that on Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is the border-collapse. removing that will restore your outer border

Comment: Thanks it work! But how do I make the rows less wide without using border-collapse?

Comment: set a width on your table

Comment: If you want your widths to be independent of the cell contents, add **table-layout: fixed;** to your table css

Answer (score 2):

You have extra  tag at few places

```
<tr><td>Label 0</td><td></tr>
<tr><td>Label 7</td><td></tr>
<tr><td>Label 8</td><td></tr>
```

Change it to like this

```
<tr><td colspan="5">Label 0</td></tr>
<tr><td>Label 1</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>Yes</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>No</td></tr>
<tr><td>Label 2</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>Yes</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>No</td></tr>
<tr><td>Label 3</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>Yes</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>No</td></tr>
<tr><td>Label 4</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>Yes</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>No</td></tr>
<tr><td>Label 5</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>Yes</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>No</td></tr>
<tr><td>Label 6</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>Yes</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>No</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="5">Label 7</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="5">Label 8</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `<td>` tag here.

```
<tr><td>Label 0</td><td></tr>
```

As well as on every row, you're adding and extra `<td>` before the closing.

You are also missing a bunch of semicolons in your style tag. It should look like this...

```
<style>
    div.box{height:.14in; width:.14in; border: 1px solid black;}
    td.box{padding:0;}
    body{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10pt;background-color:#FFFFCC; margin-top:2px; margin-left:3px;}
    .highlight{background-color:#D8DCE7;}
    .p12px{padding-left:12px; vertical-align:top;}
    table.q{width:660px; border:1px solid black; border-top-width:0; padding-left:2px;}
    table.qFirst{width:660px; border:1px solid black;}
    table{border-collapse:collapse;}
    table td{padding:1px;}
</style>
```

You should always follow conventions when you code. Make sure every case is denoted the same way. You are mixing different styles of syntax, and it makes your code harder to read.

Comment: Where are the missing semicolons in the style tag?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `table{border-collapse:collapse}` from your CSS.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e65zh0ex/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `border-collapse: collapse;` rule from all the tables and add it only to the first one, the header.

That being said, you do NOT need two tables. The `thead` element is what you should use. This element defines the table header, while the `tbody` element defines the body (doh!). So, place the headers in `thead` using the same construction as a classic table, and the data goes into `tbody`.

@see: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/thead

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep `border-collapse` add empty cells to have the same number of cells in each row, like this:

```
<tr><td>Label 0</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Label 1</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>Yes</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>No</td></tr>
<tr><td>Label 2</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>Yes</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>No</td></tr>
<tr><td>Label 3</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>Yes</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>No</td></tr>
<tr><td>Label 4</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>Yes</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>No</td></tr>
<tr><td>Label 5</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>Yes</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>No</td></tr>
<tr><td>Label 6</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>Yes</td><td><div class='box'></div></td><td>No</td></tr>
<tr><td>Label 7</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Label 8</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

Comment: that seems rather inefficient way to solve the problem.

Comment: You have to do either that or `colspan` as [@Rings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25453497/2532749) sugggests, if you don't want to remove `border-collapse`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the colspan="5" element at with the td tags that aren't a full row.

```
<tr><td colspan="5">Label 0</td></tr>
```

[As seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/s8q67vhz/)

Comment: Could you explain how this works? I see that it does

Comment: The problem was that the border only draws around a cell. With colspan, you're expanding the cell over 5 columns. So the first cell is now 5 columns wide. It is just like @mjr but it is just melted into one.

Comment: So if I put another box in one column, I would need to increase the colspan, correct?

Comment: Yes, if I understand you correctly. Each time you add an extra column you need to increase the colspan.